# android app doesnt install in version 9 and above

Tags: java, android, mobile

Good day all, pls the app that i created doesnt work on android versions 9, 10 and 11..

I tested the app on lower versions and it worked perfectly but when tested on version 9, 10 or 11, the app keeps crashing

I really appreciate if my question is answered. Thanks

Below is my build.gradle file

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}


compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myrevisedlawcoursesapp300level"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release

    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

`}

`dependencies {

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.7.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
```

}`

the error messages in my logcat. I dnt see any clues from it tho

```
02-13 07:21:45.075 308-308/? A/DEBUG: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_01
02-13 07:22:09.934 30407-30420/? A/libc: Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 1, fault addr 0xc0011 in tid 30420 (Compiler driver)
```

02-13 07:22:10.038 308-308/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
`02-13 07:22:10.039 308-308/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'TCL/5056I/POP455C:6.0.1/MMB29M/vHAJ9-0:user/release-keys' 02-13 07:22:10.039 308-308/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0' 02-13 07:22:10.039 308-308/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm' 02-13 07:22:10.039 308-308/? A/DEBUG: pid: 30407, tid: 30420, name: Compiler driver  >>> /system/bin/dex2oat <<< 02-13 07:22:10.039 308-308/? A/DEBUG: signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 1 (BUS_ADRALN), fault addr 0xc0011 02-13 07:22:10.051 308-308/? A/DEBUG:     r0 b1c6004c  r1 ffff0006  r2 000c0001  r3 ffff0006 02-13 07:22:10.051 308-308/? A/DEBUG:     r4 b1c45638  r5 b1c639ec  r6 b1c63af0  r7 00250000 02-13 07:22:10.051 308-308/? A/DEBUG:     r8 b1c63958  r9 ffffffff  sl b1c63950  fp b1c6395c 02-13 07:22:10.051 308-308/? A/DEBUG:     ip b1e522f6  sp b1e522e8  lr b1c60a18  pc b6c56904  cpsr 20070030 02-13 07:22:10.087 308-308/? A/DEBUG: backtrace: 02-13 07:22:10.087 308-308/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 000e7904  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19LocalValueNumbering16HandleInvokeArgsEPKNS_3MIREPKS0_+199) 02-13 07:22:10.087 308-308/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 000eac3d  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19LocalValueNumbering14GetValueNumberEPNS_3MIRE+608) 02-13 07:22:10.088 308-308/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 001badb3  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art8MIRGraph28ApplyGlobalValueNumberingEndEv+186) 02-13 07:22:10.088 308-308/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 001bcd9b  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art16PassDriverMEOpts9ApplyPassEPNS_14PassDataHolderEPKNS_4PassE+38) 02-13 07:22:10.088 308-308/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0016ecbb  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so 02-13 07:22:10.088 308-308/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 0016f4e7  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZNK3art13QuickCompiler7CompileEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEjNS_10InvokeTypeEtjP8_jobjectRKS1_+1390) 02-13 07:22:10.088 308-308/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 0031ed97  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art14TryFastCompileEPNS_14CompilerDriverEPNS_8CompilerEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEjNS_10InvokeTypeEtjP8_jobjectRKS4_+166) 02-13 07:22:10.088 308-308/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 0025e279  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZNK3art18OptimizingCompiler7CompileEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEjNS_10InvokeTypeEtjP8_jobjectRKS1_+180) 02-13 07:22:10.088 308-308/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 001cb7ef  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art14CompilerDriver13CompileMethodEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEjNS_10InvokeTypeEtjP8_jobjectRKS3_NS_24DexToDexCompilationLevelEb+1818) 02-13 07:22:10.088 308-308/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 001cc49b  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art14CompilerDriver12CompileClassEPKNS_26ParallelCompilationManagerEj+1954) 02-13 07:22:10.088 308-308/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 001c2c95  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so 02-13 07:22:10.088 308-308/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 00347e11  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker3RunEv+256) 02-13 07:22:10.089 308-308/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 00348449  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker8CallbackEPv+52) 02-13 07:22:10.089 308-308/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 0004169b  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+30) 02-13 07:22:10.089 308-308/? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 00019275  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6) 02-13 07:22:10.366 308-308/? A/DEBUG: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_09`
02-13 09:06:16.369 8032-8032/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    `Process: com.tcl.antivirus, PID: 8032 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.antivirus.ui.privacy.PrivacyAlarmReceiver: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider from ProcessRecord{6dab055 8032:com.tcl.antivirus/u0a88} (pid=8032, uid=10088) requires android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG or android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2732) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:150) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider from ProcessRecord{6dab055 8032:com.tcl.antivirus/u0a88} (pid=8032, uid=10088) requires android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG or android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620) at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573) at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3572) at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4778) at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2018) at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1471) at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:477) at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:435) at com.antivirus.i.a(Unknown Source) at com.antivirus.privacy.e.b(Unknown Source) at com.antivirus.privacy.e.a(Unknown Source) at com.antivirus.ui.privacy.PrivacyAlarmReceiver.a(Unknown Source) at com.antivirus.ui.privacy.PrivacyAlarmReceiver.onReceive(Unknown Source) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2725) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:150)  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)`

Comment: Please post the output of the crash message.

Comment: when i test it on my phone(which is a version 8), it shows no crash message but when i send the apk file to a phone of version 9 and above, it says "unfortunately, app has stopped"

Comment: I recommend reviewing and posting the crash output using logcat from a physical or emulated phone.

Comment: What is the purpose of this signingConfig signingConfigs.release?

Comment: Bink, I have added the crash output from my logcat

Comment: eyosiyas berketeb, the signingconfig is used to show that i have generated a signed apk for my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the app directly on a phone that uses android version 9 and the error was that i added a picture to a wrong resource directory. So i changed the location of the picture from mipmap to drawable

Thanks for all ur help

Answer (score 0):

You have a permissions problem here, in low versions of Android, when you install the app, it guarantees all the permissions, but in the latest Android APIs, you have to request permission at runtime, if you don't and for example try read your app's storage information then your app will be crash

Comment: Make sure to add all necessary permissions in your manifest and check if there are install-time permissions or runtime permissions.

Comment: Pls can u tell me the permissions i can add to the app to make it work on higher versions. Thanks sir

Comment: Can you provide a snipet to know what `PrivacyAlarmReceiver` does?

Comment: i didnt add such in my code. The app is just a simple educational app that contains revised course notes. Nothing else. Thanks

Comment: You have a RuntimeException when `PrivacyAlarmReceiver` try to init. Log cat show a `Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider` you need to have a `android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG` in your manifest. And at runtime ask user to give permission

Comment: Maybe this post help you https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting